# How to Concatenation two results into a variable

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

In PHP I'm running a mysql query and from the results I want to string together multiple columns into a single variable. Obviously my example below doesn't work, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
$var1=         $line_results[city,state,country];
```

I want var1 to become one long variable for all 3 columns that get stitched together. What is the exact syntax to stitch those 3 columns together? This is what I currently have setup and I want to merge them into one:

```
  $var1=        $line_results[city];
  $var2=        $line_results[state];
  $var3=        $line_results[country];
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php or http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.` to concatenate strings e.g.

```
$var1 = $line_results['city'] . $line_results['state'] . $line_results['country'];
```

or if they need a space:

```
$var1 = $line_results['city'] .' '. $line_results['state'] .' '. $line_results['country'];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm.  You Da Man.

Comment: @Alby No worries. Glad I could help!

Comment: Ross:   Is it possible to add a carriage return vs. a space?

Comment: @Alby you could do something like `. '<br />' `. or `. "\n\r" `.

Comment: Thanks Ross... Just what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings with a dot.
 `$var1 = $line_results[city] . $line_results[state] . $line_results[country]`